# ASP.NET MVC Bootstrap form controls not aligned properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015

In my following `ASP.NET MVC Core` project `view`, I want to display `input`, its corresponding `label` and submit button `Add` controls in the same line. but they are displaying in three separate lines, **why**?. How can I make them display in the same line (please note that the dropdown control is **correctly** showing its label and submit button `Go` in the same line). **Note**: Probably not related - but we know the content of the labels are coming from the data annotations of the corresponding model.

**View**:

```
<div class="col-md-9">

    <form asp-controller="myControllerName" asp-action="myTestAction" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <label asp-for="SelectedYear" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="SelectedYear" asp-items="Model.lstYears"></select><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">GO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <label asp-for="testDesc" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="testDesc" class="form-control"/><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Snapshot of Page display from the above View**

[image]

**UPDATE**:

After following a suggestion from the user `@RatHat` I've been able to display the three controls inline. But, still why they are not aligned left like the other three controls for dropdown. New display:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using a `.form-horizontal`, you need to specify the number of columns that each element should cover:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <!-- add the number of columns that the label should use -->
    <label asp-for="testDesc" class="control-label col-sm-2"></label>
    <!-- add the number of columns that the input should use -->
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input asp-for="testDesc" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <!-- add the number of columns that the Add button should use -->
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your suggestion has made the three controls display horizontally in one line, but it has pushed the three controls to the right, why? Please see my **UPDATE** section with another image.

Comment: @nam the controls being pushed to the right, is caused by the controls being wrapped inside a .form-horizontal. Since the controls being aligned to the right is the default behavior, it's easier to add columns to the controls on the top as well so that they are also aligned to the right. Trying to align everything to the left like if it was a normal form is possible but requires custom CSS.